# Printing the names of all the subfolders of a known directory in a remote Desktop Python

Tags: python

I would like to connect to a remote desktop using python. I have all the info (IP,username,password) needed for connecting. And then save the names of the folders of a known directory in a vector.

Example :

[image]

In this case (assuming I have the following folders in Tests directory).

I would like to save the vector [test1,test2,test3]

Answer (score -1):

```
import os
path = '/home/blablabla/test/'

test_dirs = []
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for i in dirs:
        test_dirs.append(i)

print(test_dirs)
```

try this.

Comment: But it's a remote Desktop, how would this work without first connecting?

Comment: Oh, you want to ssh using Python xD. gl with that! Didn't kinda see it at first.